# Label Text not Changing on action in javafx

Tags: javafx, label

I am creating an app in which there is a menu bar with the option of disk check but when action is performed i need to change the text in Label "lbldiskchecking". But the text in label is not changing but my other code is working fine.

```
     private void goToDiskCheck(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    lbldiskchecking.setVisible(true);
    lbldiskchecking.setText("chal ja");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/finalproject/view/DiskCheck.fxml")); 
 AnchorPane cmdPane = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load();
 Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
 Process p = null;  
    String cmd = "E:\\work\\programming\\NetBeansProjects\\FinalProject\\src\\batchfiles\\dskchk.bat";  
    try {  
        p = run.exec(cmd);  
        p.getErrorStream();   
        int exitVal = p.waitFor();
         System.out.println("RUN.COMPLETED.SUCCESSFULLY"); 
    }  
    catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
        System.out.println("ERROR.RUNNING.CMD");  
        p.destroy();  
    }  
    try {
        borderPane.setCenter(cmdPane);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Label is defined in my FXML file

```
 <center>
  <Label fx:id="lbldiskchecking" text="Checking Disk ...." visible="false" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <font>
        <Font name="AR BERKLEY" size="27.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
```

Comment: Is the text part of the BorderPane or the AnchorPane you just loaded from fxml?

Comment: Label is the part of Border Pane ... i am loading the anchor Pane ( another FXML) in center of Border PAne

Comment: Edit your question to show where the label is declared (and initialized, if appropriate)

Comment: I have edited my FXML code of Label and i have defined Label lbldiskchecking in starting of Controller

Comment: I made a guess as to what is wrong - you haven't really shown enough code to know what is wrong (and definitely not enough to reproduce the problem). In future, consider creating an [executable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, since you haven't posted enough code to reproduce the problem.

It looks like your label is in the center of the border pane. In the action handler, you load a new FXML file and put the content of the file in the center of the border pane. This replaces the label, so it is no longer part of the scene graph. You need to put the label in a different part of the scene.

Comment: nope.I already tried that but it does not solved the problem.

Comment: So please post enough code to reproduce the problem. You can't really expect people to just guess what you're doing.